# Set mouse pointer location to the selected item in a combo box

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox, mouse

I have a combobox that drops up instead of down. I'm setting the selected item to the one on top of the list.  I'd like to move my mouse pointer to point to it, so that the user that wants to click on that item doesn't have to move his mouse. I found how to move the pointer, it is with this command:

```
Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = New System.Drawing.Point(x,y)
```

but I need to know how to get the location of the selected item in the combobox.

Comment: Just a caution, moving the mouse for the user is an unusual behavior that many users may not appreciate.

Comment: Yeah, the reason is that 99% of the time they'll click the item at the top of the list,which is quite a distance from the combo's down button. If I could drop the list down instead of up, this would be a non-issue, but my combobox is at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: You might also consider making that item the default selected item so they don't need to drop down the list at all.

Comment: What Igby said. Change the default selected item so they don't have to click anything at all. Moving the cursor is not appreciated and is definitely not the right way of going about this. I appreciate that you're trying to make it easier on the user, but this will probably just confuse them. Use code like: `myComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0` in the form's constructor.

Comment: I realize it's unorthodox. I already set the top item as the selected one when the list opens, but in order to process it, the user must click on it (or press enter). A user must make an active choice, ie. not selecting any item and taking a default is not an option.

Comment: You need a *button* then to indicate that the selection is confirmed. (Or do the processing for the default item before the form ever loads. It's unclear why that isn't happening anyway.) It's not just unorthodox, it's *broken*. There are all sorts of things that can go wrong, even with hacks like `GetWindowRect` and trying to calculate the height of each item and count the number of indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When searching for destinations on traveling sites, they often present a sorted list of destinations, but have the 2-3 most common destinations duplicated in the list at the beginning. That way you both comply to standard behaiviour and make the life easy for the end user.

I would add a quicklist at the end of the combobox with the items that is most used so they are easy to select without needing to move the mouse more than a couple of milimeters. The sorted list will go above if the user want to select anything else. When program starts set last item as selected (the "Select destination"-item).

(Then I would explain to the customer that this is what users expect, not mousepointers that move around by itself and hope that the customer have a change of mind.)

Like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you all for comments. I managed to convince my client that reversing the sort order of the entire data set is an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is the fact that the first item is too far from the combo: can't you invert the ordering of the items? so that the first, and most clicked item, became the last one, and due to that will be very near to the combo. Maybe you can also insert an empty item between the most clicked one, and the others, to make it stand out.

**UPDATE 1**
So, if the control is a standard winform combobox, you can try to check the value of the property ItemHeight, and then multiply this value by the number of items in the dropdown, this should give you the position of the fist item in the dropdown.
With this value maybe you'll be able to calculate where to put the mouse cursor.

Caveats:

- you need to check if this works on all computer
- you need to test if it works correctly with different font/font size (the ItemHeight property is readonly, and is bound to the selected font/font size)
- you should try what happen when user change the system font size magnification (120dpi 125%/150%) Note that WinXP and Win7 handle this parameter in different ways
- check if on-screen there is enought space for all the items in the dropdown
- configure the dropdown to have a MaxDropDownItems > than the number in the dropdown list

Comment: Indeed, another preferable option to moving the cursor.

Comment: Items are sorted in ascending order for a reason. Client doesn't want to change that. It is his request that the mouse pointer jumps. I'm just complying.

Comment: It's not going to work out right. There are too many problems with it. The code would require you to make too many assumptions, and those assumptions would be true too infrequently. It is indeed the client's job to make requests. But it is also your job as the programmer (i.e., the *expert*) to explain to the client why what they are proposing is a bad idea and/or won't work. It's also your job to propose a suitable alternative. If they understood all of the caveats and limitations, they wouldn't need you; they'd just write the software themselves.